# Trying to Call Google Cloud Function, Where Do I Put The Function URL And /path/to/credentials.json in CloudFunctionsServiceClient?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I copied this code from https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/functions/latest/functions/v1.cloudfunctionsserviceclient:

```
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
   */
  /**
   *  Required. The name of the function to be called.
   */
  // const name = 'abc123'
  /**
   *  Required. Input to be passed to the function.
   */
  // const data = 'abc123'

  // Imports the Functions library
  const {CloudFunctionsServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/functions').v1;

  // Instantiates a client
  const functionsClient = new CloudFunctionsServiceClient();

  async function callCallFunction() {
    // Construct request
    const request = {
      name,
      data,
    };

    // Run request
    const response = await functionsClient.callFunction(request);
    console.log(response);
  }

  callCallFunction();
```

This doesn't help me that much. I have a cloud function (in Python) that simply prints "hello world" or something simple like that. My cloud function can only be run through a "service account" that I created and I downloaded the `.json` file containing my credentials for this service account.

I'm making a Next.js app (with typescript) and I want to call this function in the app. So keeping the above example in mind where do I put these variables?

```
https://us-central1-<projectname>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionname>
/path/to/credentials.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `credentials.json` by passing it on the constructor. Also you won't be needing to explicitly call the URL of the function. Properly defining the function in `name` should tell your code to use the function.

Using your code, I modified it to include the use of the `credentials.json` and defining of `name`. You can check this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call) to construct the `name` properly.

```
  const project = 'your-project' // update with your project name
  const location = 'us-central1' //update this with the actual location of your function
  const func_name = 'function-1' // update with your function name
  const name = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}/functions/${func_name}`
  const keyFilename = '/credentials.json' // update with the full path of your json
  const data = '{"message":"test"}' // update with your request body

  // Imports the Functions library
  const {CloudFunctionsServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/functions').v1;

  // Instantiates a client
  const options = {keyFilename}; 
  const functionsClient = new CloudFunctionsServiceClient(options);

  async function callCallFunction() {
    // Construct request
    const request = {
      name,
      data,
    };

    // Run request
    const response = await functionsClient.callFunction(request);
    console.log(response);
  }

  callCallFunction();
```

Test run:

[image]

Comment: I got `details: "Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.call' denied on resource 'projects/<myprojectname>/locations/us-central1/functions/<myfunctionname>' (or resource may not exist)."` Maybe it's not reading my keyStore correctly

Comment: @NextNightFlyer does your service account have the correct permissions for calling a cloud function?

Comment: Yeah, I was actually able to do it using `new GoogleAuth` instead of `new CloudFunctionsServiceClient`